# View cross project Area Path during Task creation

Tags: azure-devops

I work on multiple projects, and for a common overview of my Work Items I use Cross Project Queries.

Now the problem is, if I create a new Work Item (within that Querie view), per default the Work Item "Area" and "Iteration" is the one from the current project. In the drop-down menu of "Area" and "Iteration" within the task creation window, the other projects are not listed and can't be searched.

Currently, I have to manually switch to the related project, to create the WIT, or "Move to Team project,... " after creating the WIT in the wrong project.

I am the Organization Owner so it should not be a permission problem.
I am also part of every team in every project.

Does anybody know if I missed something, or is this feature just not implemented in the Task Creation (only afterwards via three dots, "Move to Team project,... ").

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently unavailable. You will have to use the "Move to Team project" option.